# Sort dictionary by value and ignore some values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

So there are two tasks that are to be performed simultaneously on a dictionary.

1. Sort the dictionary and extract the top 10 keys along with their values
2. Ignore keys which have a certain value while reporting top 10

For e.g.

```
my_dict = { 'abc': 10, 'def':20, 'ghi':100, 'jkl':30, 'mno':101}
```

So, if I want top 3 while ignoring keys with value `100` and `101` is

```
result_top3 = [ ('jkl',30), ('def',20), ('abc',10)]
```

Right now I am using the following :

```
my_result = dict(Counter(my_dict).most_common()[:3])
```

but it has two problems:

1. I don't know how to add a filter in my expression to ignore certain values
2. It returns a dictionary, in which the keys may be unsorted although they would be top 10 values.

I was hoping if there was a way to do it in one go, or a more Pythonic and efficient way instead of doing it in 2 steps, like removing the keys I don't want and then sorting.

**EDIT** : It is not necessary to sort the complete dictionary. I just need to extract the top 10 results along with their values.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't made for sorting. Perhaps [orderedDict](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/03/24/python-201-ordereddict/) can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to filter data

```
[items for items in my_dict.items() if items[1] < 100]
```

to sort dict by key value

```
sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])
```

and full your solution

```
sorted([items for items in my_dict.items() if items[1] < 100], key=lambda x: -x[1])[:3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this-

```
>>> my_dict = { 'abc': 10, 'def':20, 'ghi':100, 'jkl':30, 'mno':101}
>>> dict_tuple = my_dict.items()
>>> print dict_tuple
[('jkl', 30), ('abc', 10), ('ghi', 100), ('def', 20), ('mno', 101)]
>>> dict_tuple.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> print dict_tuple
[('abc', 10), ('def', 20), ('jkl', 30), ('ghi', 100), ('mno', 101)]
 >>> print dict(dict_tuple[:3])
 {'jkl': 30, 'abc': 10, 'def': 20}
```

Comment: In Python 3 will not work, since `dict.items()` will return so called *view objects* that don't have `sort` method.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same as @BearBrown's answer. But using built-in features and break it down, for doing it step-by-step:

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [2]: my_dict = { 'abc': 10, 'def':20, 'ghi':100, 'jkl':30, 'mno':101}
# filter values out, can be `if v >= 100`(this is depends on condition)
In [3]: filtered_values = ((k, v) for k, v in my_dict.items() if v not in [100, 101])

In [4]: filtered_values
Out[4]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1060a9ca8>

In [5]: import operator
# sort by values(second element of key-value tuple) in reverse order
In [6]: top_three = sorted(filtered_values, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:3]

In [7]: top_three
Out[7]: [('jkl', 30), ('def', 20), ('abc', 10)]

In [8]: OrderedDict(top_three)
Out[8]: OrderedDict([('jkl', 30), ('def', 20), ('abc', 10)])
```

In the end you will get [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)(`dict` that have order) as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it stepwise:

```
my_dict = { 'abc': 10, 'def':20, 'ghi':100, 'jkl':30, 'mno':101}

filterIt = [(x[1],x[0]) for x in my_dict.items() if x[1] not in [101,100]]

sortOfSorted = sorted(filterIt,  reverse = True)

print (my_dict)
print(filterIt)
print (sortOfSorted)
```

The result is a list of tuples with the "value" on `[0]` - no lambda needed for sorting that way as tuples get sorted by `[0]` first, then `[1]`

Dictionarys like sets are inherently unordered. And to get the top 10 out of anything you need to sort all of the items to find the biggest ones.

**Output**:

```
{'jkl': 30, 'abc': 10, 'ghi': 100, 'def': 20, 'mno': 101}
[(30, 'jkl'), (10, 'abc'), (20, 'def')]
[(30, 'jkl'), (20, 'def'), (10, 'abc')]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:
`operator.itemgetter(1)` will sort dict by `value`; and `operator.itemgetter(0)` will sort dict by `key`

```
>>> import operator
>>> my_dict = { 'abc': 10, 'def':20, 'ghi':100, 'jkl':30, 'mno':101}
>>> sorted_my_dict = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> sorted_my_dict
[('abc', 10), ('def', 20), ('jkl', 30), ('ghi', 100), ('mno', 101)]
>>> sorted_my_dict[:3]
[('abc', 10), ('def', 20), ('jkl', 30)]
```